# How to make Python to be Client-Side?

Tags: javascript, python, client-side

I know that Python can be a server-side language but is there a way to make python act like a client side language (like javascript) i just want to try it out if its possible thank you

Comment: There is django

Comment: Django is not client-side technology.

Comment: Not really, but you can look into things like https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt

Comment: Or you could just learn javascript :-P

Comment: I know Javascript but its fun to mix things sometime you know @Stefan Porchmann

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compile your python to javascript with **[Pyjs](http://pyjs.org/)**.

Note that if you use Skulpt, Skulpt will NOT let you create full websites or actual javascript code that can run inside browsers. For this, you must use Pyjs. Pyjs essentially **transforms your Python code into actual Javascript**, so you can run the resulting Javascript in any browser, or host it as a website.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.skulpt.org/  it is an entirely in the browser implementation of Python.

Comment: @GregSchmit yeah well you could technically adapt the code to work like CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try this: http://pypyjs.org/.

It uses the PyPy python interpreter, compiled for the web via emscripten, with a custom JIT backend that emits asm.js code at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want online python compiler to test the code/snippet that run on browser, try [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you know python and want everything to be in python. Well dont do it. Seriously dont even use that skulpt solution that was posted. Not because it wouldnt work. Its more because browsers only understand Javascript as a front end program. No other language is understood. If you understand python, using javascript should be a piece of cake and you might as well start that. If you really want to use python, atleast transpile into javascript using http://pyjs.org/

Comment: Well I love Javascript, its my first programming language even but I just want to know if such thing is possible. Thank you for your suggestion, appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Pyodide gives you a full, standard Python interpreter that runs
> entirely in the browser, with full access to the browser’s Web APIs.

article
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/04/pyodide-bringing-the-scientific-python-stack-to-the-browser/

download
https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide

Comment: From: How do I write a good answer? guideline
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.